# Changing Encoding of Text Files Using Python: It's Not Happening

Tags: python, windows, encoding, utf-8

Upon copying or pretty much touching files in any way, Windows changes their encoding to its default 1252: Western European. In the text editor I'm using, EditPad Pro Plus, I can see and convert the encoding. I trust that this conversion works, because I've been working with files between Windows and UNIX, and I know that when my text editor changes encodings, the files are read correctly in UNIX where they caused problems before.

I would like to convert files en masse. So I'm attempting to do that using Python in Windows 10, called from either Powershell (using Python v 3.6.2) or CygWin (using Python v 2.7.13). I see both `codecs` and `io` used for the job, and commentary that `io` is the proper way for Python 3.

But the files are not converted -- `codecs` or `io`. The script below successfully copies the files, but my text editor reports them as 1252 still. And the UniversalDetector (in the commented out portions of the script below) reports their encoding as "ascii".

What needs to happen to get these to convert successfully?

```
import sys
import os
import io
#from chardet.universaldetector import UniversalDetector

BLOCKSIZE = 1048576
#detector = UniversalDetector()

#def get_encoding( current_file ):
#    detector.reset()
#    for line in file(current_file):
#        detector.feed(line)
#        if detector.done: break
#    detector.close()
#    return detector.result['encoding']

def main():
    src_dir = ""

    if len( sys.argv ) > 1:
        src_dir = sys.argv[1]

    if os.path.exists( src_dir ):
        dest_dir = src_dir[:-2]
        for file in os.listdir( src_dir ):
            with io.open( os.path.join( src_dir, file ), "r", encoding='cp1252') as source_file:
                with io.open( os.path.join( dest_dir, file ), "w", encoding='utf8') as target_file:
                    while True:
                        contents = source_file.read( BLOCKSIZE )
                        if not contents:
                            break
                        target_file.write( contents )
#print( "Encoding of " + file + ": " + get_encoding( os.path.join( dest_dir, file ) ) )
    else:
        print( 'The specified directory does not exist.' )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I've tried some variations such as opening the file as UTF8, calling read() without the blocksize, and, originally, the encodings were specified a little differently. They all successfully copy the files, but do not encode them as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASCII is the common subset to a whole lot of encodings. It is a subset of UTF-8, Latin-1, and cp1252-- and of the whole [ISO-8859](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859#The_parts_of_ISO.2FIEC_8859) family which has encodings for Russian, Greek etc. If your files are really ASCII, there's nothing to convert and your system is only saying "cp1252" because the files are *compatible* with this. You could add a BOM to tag a file as UTF (encoding `utf-8-sig`), but frankly I don't see the point. UTF doesn't actually need it, because UTF files are recognizable by the structure of multi-byte characters.

If you want to experiment with encodings, use text that contains non-ASCII characters: French, Russian, Chinese, or even English with some accented words (or the silly directed quotes that Microsoft applications like to insert). Save the words "Wikipédia en français" in a file and repeat your experiments, and you'll get very different results.

I **strongly** recommend using Python 3 for this, and for anything else to do with character encodings. The Python 2 approach to encodings results in a lot of pointless confusion, and was in fact one of the major reasons for breaking compatibility and introducing Python 3.
As a bonus, in Python 3 you can just use `open()` with an `encoding` argument. You don't need any modules to change encodings.

Comment: So it may just be a charade all around, which "encoding" a file is? because they aren't marked, and mine are generally using only the basic ASCII range, except maybe the occasional character interpreted differently by 1252 or UTF-8? So it's not going to be noticed.

Comment: This looks like the answer, because I tried it with the "utf-8-sig" encoding, and my text editor definitely picks up that it's UTF-8 now.

Comment: t's not at all a charade if your file contains any French, Russian, Chinese, or even English with a couple of accented words. Or just English with the silly directed quotes that Microsoft applications like to insert. All these use non-ascii characters, and you need the right encoding or you get nonsense. Save the words "Wikipédia en français" in a file and repeat your experiments, you'll get very different results.